# category links are giving 404 error

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

My category links comming from mega-menu extension is not working (giving 404 error) . I have tried almost everything suggested on magento stack exchange or any other site used for question answers , discussions etc , things which i have tried are admin->search engine optimization etc . but the end i came to end with no good resuls . i want to know if something i can do ? i am using magento 2.2.6 is this is the bug in magento 2.2.6?